# What is the complete list of keys in ClipboardActionTransformations.xml to configure Remote Desktop

Tags: keyboard, mapping, remote-desktop

There is very little documentation on `ClipboardActionTransformations.xml` which can be edited to map keys in Remote Desktop.

For example, if I want to map the (host Mac) <kbd>command</kbd> key to be the (client Windows) <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, I would use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- transformation for clipboard actions (cut copy paste) -->
<!-- layout specific -->
<layouts>
    <layout name="default">
        <transformations>
            <transform>
                <from command="1" key="A" />
                <to control="1" key="A" />
            </transform>
        </transformations>
    </layout>
</layouts>
```

repeating `transform` for each key.

This file should be copied into the Remote Desktop app after it is updated.

```
sudo cp ~/ClipboardActionTransformations.xml /Applications/Microsoft\ Remote\ Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/Keyboard
```

What are all the other keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing the contents of `/Applications/Microsoft\ Remote\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Remote\ Desktop` I have found:

- `Num1`, `Num2`, etc.
- `F1`, `F2`, etc.
- `LeftBrace`, `RightBrace` (or Bracket?)
- `Return`, `Tab`, `Delete`, `Escape`
- `Comma`, `SemiColon`, `Period`
- `Slash`, `BackSlash`
- `Space`
- `Equal`, `Minus`
- `LeftCommand`, `RightCommand`
- `LeftShift`, `RightShift`
- `LeftControl`, `RightControl`
- `LeftOption`, `RightOption`
- `CapsLock`
- `Apps`
- `ForwardDelete`, `Delete`, `Insert`,
- `PageUp`, `PageDown`, `Home`, `End`
- `UpArrow`, `RightArrow`, `DownArrow`, `LeftArrow`

and

- `Keypad1`, `Keypad2`, etc.
- `KeypadDecimal`
- `KeypadMultiple`, `KeypadDivide`, `KeypadPlus`, `KeypadMinus`
- `KeypadEnd`
- `KeypadEnter`
- KeypadCl???

Modifiers are:

- `control`
- `command`
- `option`
- `shift`

Note:

1. most of the symbols are truncated, so I'm guessing at them (I couldn't guess one keypad symbol)
2. I could not find the symbol for <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd>
3. I haven't tested them all, so some may be incorrect
4. I haven't had much luck mapping the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, in particular, when I press <kbd>command</kbd>, but don't press another key, the Start menu pops up which is annoying
5. I haven't managed to get the Windows clipboard to show when pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, but it does show when pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> which is good enough